# Почему не отображается CollectionVIew внутри ScrollView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Почему не отображается CollectionVIew внутри ScrollView? Скролл работает, всё сделал правильно, а вот CollectionView и всё, что внутри него - не отображается при запуске. В коллекции будут картинки с лейблом, при клики на которые будет переход на другое активити и в зависимости от того, на какой блок нажал пользователь будут передаваться определяться параметры. На фото видна иерархия. Что я делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вы UICollectionView кладете на UIScrollView?

Comment: @Vitaly потому-что таких плиток будет > 15 и надо будет скролить вниз чтобы другие увидеть.

Comment: У UICollectionView есть свой скролл.

Comment: @Vitaly то-есть scrollView  вообще не нужен?

Comment: Получается не нужен )

Comment: @Vitaly создал новый проект, поместил внутри collectionView Cell label, но его всё равно не видно...